# Python: Set window focus on terminal

Tags: python, gnuplot

I have a Python application that opens some plots for me and then asks the user for input. The problem is that after opening the plot, the focus isn't on the terminal anymore, so you have to click or tab to it manually.

I would like to set the focus to the terminal window with Python - is that possible?

I'm using gnuplot.py, maybe there is an option to open the plot in the background?

Comment: The solution may depend on your OS and/or window manager. What are you using?

Comment: mac os x... but it's not worth spending so much time on it.

Comment: What is your python code so far? can you show a minimal example please?